# php array empty - how to get NOT

Tags: php, arrays

```
if($_POST['cropProfileData'] == undefined || $_POST['cropProfileData'] == null || $_POST['cropProfileData'] == 0) {
    echo "NO process profile photo....";
}else{
    echo "YES process profile photo....";
}
```

this works fine - it shows me if the array is empty.

The catch is I only need the 'echo "YES process profile photo...".

How can I get the NOT of the above IF statement? I've tried added '!' after the if - eg: `if!(` and I've tried added '!' after each of the 3 statements.

Is there a way to get the NOT of this statement - will save me a having to include the else which is pointless code.

thx

PS: the reason for this is to see if the array is empty.

Comment: You have posted PHP code, but tagged it with "jQuery". There is no PHP vlaue like `undefined` Well, it's monday…

Comment: Have you tried this - `$_POST['cropProfileData'] != undefined || `

Comment: yes I have... I'll update the question... thankyou n sorry

Comment: What is this `undefined` constant?

Comment: `Undefined` must have come from JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `!empty( $_POST[ 'cropProfileData' ] )` will cover all those cases (although `undefined` is not used in PHP unless it's some constant).

```
if( !empty( $_POST[ 'cropProfileData' ] ) ) {
    echo "YES process profile photo....";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't strictly check for a non-empty array.

Answer (score 2):

**Theory**

The negative expression is simply this:

```
if (!($_POST['cropProfileData'] == undefined || $_POST['cropProfileData'] == null || $_POST['cropProfileData'] == 0)) {
```

According to [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the expression could also be written as:

```
if ($_POST['cropProfileData'] != undefined && $_POST['cropProfileData'] != null && $_POST['cropProfileData'] != 0) {
```

**Practice**

To test if something is `undefined` you should use `isset()`, for example:

```
$_POST['cropProfileData'] == undefined || $_POST['cropProfileData'] == null
```

Should be written as:

```
!isset($_POST['cropProfileData'])
```

To specifically test if an array is not empty:

```
isset($_POST['cropProfileData']) && is_array($_POST['cropProfileData']) && count($_POST['cropProfileData'])
```

Or, simpler:

```
if (!empty($_POST['cropProfileData']) && is_array($_POST['cropProfileData'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/*
if($a == undefined || $b == null || $c == 0) {
    echo "NO process profile photo....";
}else{
    echo "YES process profile photo....";
}
*/


if($a != undefined && $b != null && $c != 0) {
    echo "NO process profile photo....";
}else{
    echo "YES process profile photo....";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check that array is empty or not

like

```
if(!empty( $_POST[ 'cropProfileData' ] )){echo "YES process profile photo....";}
```